# Python script to save image from xlsx file to disk

Tags: python

I do have an excel worksheet which has various images included inside. I want to store those images as PNG or JPEG files on the disk. Can anyone suggest if there is any solution to achieve this?

I have tried with python xlrd module but it ignores images inside xlsx.

Comment: If xlrd cannot do it, better change your programming language. I'm fairly sure it's quite straightforward in VBA.

Comment: Can you see the image filenames if you try `import zipfile` and then print `zipfile.ZipFile("your_filename_here.xlsx").namelist()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going off of @DSM's comment, this chunk of code works to extract embedded `jpeg` or `jpg` files from an `xlsx` file. They will end up in the directory from which you run the program, nested in the folders that are shown in the original archive contents:

```
import zipfile
XLSname = "/Users/user/myfile.xlsx"

EmbeddedFiles = zipfile.ZipFile(XLSname).namelist()
ImageFiles = [F for F in EmbeddedFiles if F.count('.jpg') or F.count('.jpeg') ]

for Image in ImageFiles:
    zipfile.ZipFile(XLSname).extract(Image)
```

Comment: Can we get a mapping of the position where that image is present this way?

Comment: Hi Girish. I'm not sure how that info is embedded in the file.