# How to extract image with cell information from xlsx?

Tags: javascript, python, excel, xlsx, exceljs

I have a `xlsx` file containing images in each row of a column with several other fileds. I want to extract those images with some information of the cell like, cell id or row num, so that I can map those image back to the information given in the sheet later.

I will be using that information to do further analysis.

I tried this:

```
import zipfile
XLSname = "/Users/user/myfile.xlsx"

EmbeddedFiles = zipfile.ZipFile(XLSname).namelist()
ImageFiles = [F for F in EmbeddedFiles if F.count('.jpg') or F.count('.jpeg') ]

for Image in ImageFiles:
    zipfile.ZipFile(XLSname).extract(Image)
```

as mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19306015/7570548

But the image I got with this method don't have any info using which I can map them back to their row in which they were present in the file.

I want some cell or row info to be associated with the image.